# Reverse String in Java without using any Temporary String,Char or String Builder

Tags: java, string, reverse, temp

Is it possible to reverse `String` in Java without using any of the temporary variables like `String`, `Char[]` or `StringBuilder`?

Only can use `int`, or `int[]`.

Comment: Is this homework? Wouldn't using `int` or `int[]` constitute temporaries?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ReverseStringTest.htm

Comment: Any method that reverses a string would have to rely on temporary information, whether or not it's encapsulated away.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: he said he can't have StringBuffers or such like

Comment: Its not homework, its just something came into my mind to ask candidate for job interview question, I myself is working on how to do it without temp variables.

Comment: @birryree, int or int [] cant store String/Char. we can use data types which don't store sting/char

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, string buffer is again the same thing :)

Comment: I think this one's been hammered to death, e.g., on [CodeMonkey](http://codemonkeyism.com/java-interview-questions-write-a-string-reverser-and-use-recursion/).  An int[] is just a different flavor of temporary.

Comment: Create a JNI call, passing the string into the C function, and then get a pointer to the char * from the jstring struct, and then you can reverse the char * in place. No use of other classes or indeed object creation necessary. May not be exactly what is required though.

Comment: @kaibuki You want to ask candidates an interview question that you couldn't answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050310/java-reverse-string-without-temp-string-array-stringbuilder-substring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String reverseMe = "reverse me!";
for (int i = 0; i < reverseMe.length(); i++) {
    reverseMe = reverseMe.substring(1, reverseMe.length() - i)
        + reverseMe.substring(0, 1)
        + reverseMe.substring(reverseMe.length() - i, reverseMe.length());
 }
 System.out.println(reverseMe);
```

Output:

```
!em esrever
```

Just for the fun of it, of course using StringBuffer would be better, here I'm creating new Strings for each Iteration, the only difference is that I'm not introducing a new reference, and I've only an int counter.

Comment: This is brilliant !! Thanks for the perspective!

Answer (score 10):

The objects of the Java String class are immutable - their contents *cannot* be altered after being created.

You *will* need at least two temporary objects - one for the final result and one for the intermediate values - even if you do find a way to avoid using a local variable.

EDIT:

That said, since you can use `int[]` you may be able to cheat.

Since `char` can be assigned to `int`, you can use [`String.charAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) to create an `int` array with the character values in reverse order. Or you may be allowed to use `String.toCharArray()` to get a `char` array that will be copied over to your `int[]` temporary.

Then you use the variable that holds the reference to your original string (or the result variable, if you are allowed one) to start from an empty string (easily obtainable with a direct assignment or `String.substring()`) and use `String.concat()` to create the final result.

In no case, however, will you be able to swap the characters in-place as you would do in C/C++.

EDIT 2:

Here's my version which does not use StringBuffer/Builders internally:

```
int r[] = new int[s.length()];

int idx = r.length - 1;

for (int i : s.toCharArray()) {
    r[idx--] = i;
}

s = s.substring(0, 0);

for (int i : r) {
    s = s.concat(String.valueOf((char)i));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "Hello World!";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    s = s.substring(1, s.length() - i) + s.charAt(0) + s.substring(s.length() - i);
}
System.out.println(s); // !dlroW olleH
```

No temporary variables! :)

Answer (score 5):

One of many ways:

```
    String str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    int len = str.length();
    for (int i = (len-1); i >= 0; --i) 
        str += str.charAt(i);
    str = str.substring(len);

    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String reverseStr(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    }

    return reverseStr(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can use an int, you can assign an int a char value:

```
String aString = "abc";

int intChar = aString.charAt(0);
```

You will have to convert from the int back to the char to assign it to aString.charAt(2).

I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

First append the string to itself in reverse manner. Then take the second half out of it.

```
  public class RevString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="string";
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            s+=s.charAt(i);
        }
        s=s.substring(s.length()/2, s.length());
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any collection,StringBulider, StringBuffer or temp array reverse the string. Simple and crisp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "Hello World";
    String rev = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w|\\W]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while (m.find()) {
        rev = m.group()+rev;
    }
    System.out.println("Reverse==" + rev);
}
```

Output

> Reverse==dlroW olleH

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
 static St`enter code here`ring reverseString(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            str = str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i) + str.substring(i + 1, str.length() - 1 - i) + str.charAt(i);
        } else {
            str = str.substring(0, i) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)
                    + str.substring(i + 1, str.length() - 1 - i) + str.charAt(i)
                    + str.substring(str.length() - i, str.length());
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String s = "ABCDE";
    System.out.println(Test.reverseString(s));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Welcome";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();){
  System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length()-1));
  str = str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
}
```

Except for loop variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can use class java.lang.StringBuilder:

```
String reservedString = new StringBuilder(str).reserve().toString();
```

Comment: the OP said without StringBuilder

Comment: The question says without using StringBuilder library