# JAVA - Reverse String without temp String, array, Stringbuilder, substring

Tags: java, string, char, substring, reverse

I have a question for you.
So, I have to reverse a String with this requirement :

1. Only use : 1 variable string (for input), 1 variable char & 1 variable int
2. Can't use another string, string builder, list, array or collections
3. Output result assigned in input variable
4. Length of input variable can't be increase
5. Can't use function substring

And then I try this, is this correct?

```
  String str = "Hello World";  

  System.out.println("Before : "+str);

  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){

   str = new String(str.getBytes(), 1, str.length()-1-i) + new String(str.getBytes(), 0, 1) + new String(str.getBytes(), str.length()-i, i);

   System.out.println(str);

  }

  System.out.println("After : "+str);
```

Output :

Before : Hello World

ello WorldH

llo WorldeH

lo WorldleH

o WorldlleH

WorldolleH

World olleH

orldW olleH

rldoW olleH

ldroW olleH

dlroW olleH

dlroW olleH

After : dlroW olleH

Comment: using 1 variable means not using additional memory.. cant use new String!.. correct me if wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to the task, something like this:

```
public static String reverse(String source, int from) {
    if (source.length()-from == 1) {
        return source.charAt(from)+"";
    }
    return reverse(source, from+1) + source.charAt(from);
}
```

Comment: This solution is using two strings reverse and source.

Comment: no, if I assign the result to the source variable I will have only one String variable.

Comment: Check his requirement: Only use : 1 variable string (for input), 1 variable char & 1 variable int

Comment: Yes, and this solution completely fulfills those requirements. Where do you see two String variables I do not underestand.

Comment: String source    String reverse   are those not two different strings ?!!

Comment: `source.charAt(from)+""` is compiled to `new StringBuilder(source.charAt(from).toString()).append("")`

Comment: his proposed solution doesnt fulfill the requirement as well that's why he posted the question. check @karthikmanchala comment

Comment: I'm not using StringBuilder directly, so does it really matter in this case to which construction it will be compiled?

Comment: I am really not sure why you're arguing this: it's very clear:
 Only use : 1 variable string (for input)
Can't use another string

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker he can't use another variable of type String, but he **has** to be allowed to use other String instances. Otherwise, how could he even get the result and assign it to the input? Strings are immutable.

Comment: That's my point , fulfilling his requirements aren't possible in JAVA (As far as i know) so even the solution he proposed is wrong. There's no way he can use the same string in Java for both transactions.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I agree with you. I think this is something like an academic task, where solution might seem right, but also it brings a lot to discussion about the language implementation details.

Comment: reverse a String in JAVA in place is Impossible giving his requirements . other than that there are a lot of ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

String is an immutable class in java any methods which seem to modify it always return a new string object with modification.
So the answer is, NO you cannot reverse a String in-place in Java.
Java String's are implemented as wrappers around a char array, which is hidden from you (i.e. you can only get copies of this array via normal means).

Comment: At some level, @VladLezhnin's answer seems right.. because we can use 1 variable char at our disposal.. and he did the same thing by using `charAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Only use : 1 variable string (for input), 1 variable char & 1 variable int

This implies, that the desired solution is:

- Take character from position `n` from String, store to character variable.
- Move variable `m` to `n` (in string).
- restore cached char from character variable to position `m`.
- repeat until string is fully processed.

This is a typical question asked for "basic" programming languages. However Java does not allow for this, as it leaks the option to set a character based on position within a string.

While this is a *no brainer* in other languages, java has no option to set values based on an index for Strings.

```
public static String reverse(String str){
        char c;
        int i = 0;

        for (i=0; i< str.length() / 2; i++){
            c = str.charAt(i);

            //this would be required to match your requirements.
            str[i] = str.charAt(str.length() -1 -i);    
            str[str.length() -1 -i] = c;            
        }

        return str;
    }
```

but in java, you can only do:

```
public static String reverse(String str){
    char c;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i< str.length() / 2; i++){
        c = str.charAt(i);
        char[] temp = str.toCharArray();
        temp[i] = str.charAt(str.length() -1-i);
        temp[str.length() -1 -i] = c;
        str = new String(temp);
    }

    return str;
}
```

which creates additional `char` arrays and new `String` objects... Even if you could lower this to one additional char array by declaring it out of the `for`- loop, it does no longer match the requirement.

I think the guy designing the question was thinking in "C" or "php", where index-based access on strings is possible.

If a String would equal a char-array (which it does in some older languages, that might be the origin of this exercise) it would look like this:

```
public static char[] reverse(char[] str){
    char c;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i< str.length / 2; i++){
        c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[str.length -1-i];
        str[str.length -1 -i] = c;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any collection,StringBulider, StringBuffer or temp array reverse the string. Simple and crisp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "Hello World";
    String rev = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w|\\W]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while (m.find()) {
        rev = m.group()+rev;
    }
    System.out.println("Reverse==" + rev);
}
```

Output

> Reverse==dlroW olleH

Hope it helps :)